# How can I add a variables into Notification Center on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I have managed to cobble this together:

You can run it in your Terminal, it is harmless, and will output results only to notification center:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "The url(s) are on your clipboard from Droppings.app" with title "Droppings has finished sharing your file(s)" subtitle "Some Some title"'
```

Ideally, I want to add `pbpaste` in the "Some title" section, but I get the literal string.  I tried creating a variable, and yet still get the literal string instead.

I tried building the entire string up as one variable, which in the Terminal, echo'd out works, but in Notification Center, I get the actually literal variable as a string.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this syntax quite easy rather than single-exited, double-double quoted contortions:

```
echo pbcopiedtext | pbcopy

echo display notification \"Message is $(pbpaste)\" with title \"Funky Title\"  | osascript
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your method better too!  It allows me to work up a lot of code in other languages and it just piped is and out of AppleSript.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the shell, anything within single quotes (`'`) is taken verbatim. No substitutions are performed.

You can substitute the pasteboard contents into the string using something like this:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "The url(s) are on your clipboard from Droppings.app" with title "Droppings has finished sharing your file(s)" subtitle "Some title '"$(pbpaste)"'"'
```

I end the single quote, open a double quote (so the contents of the pasteboard will be considered part of the single argument even if it contains spaces), substitute the output of the `pbpaste` command, close the double quote, re-open the single quote, and resume with the rest of the string.

This works, except that if the pasteboard contents contains stuff that `osascript` (i.e. AppleScript) treats as special, like quote characters, that can affect how `osascript` parses the resulting text. To fix that, you'll have to escape the pasteboard contents to be safe against interpretation by AppleScript, which is beyond the scope of this question.